# Finding the correct mosaic art dimensions for a pixelated image to film canister ratio

Tags: pixel, pixelate

I would like to make art out of film canisters. I would like to keep the canisters in their original shape which is 1inch wide by 1.75inch tall. I want to be able to input an image - pixelate the image - replace pixels with the corresponding film canisters. The colors are limited but do not have to exactly match the images color profile.

I tried to pixelate the image in an online pixelated converter, but I am not sure how to change the dimensions to fit the dimensions of the film canisters.